# Setting date of birth for new objects in java

Tags: java

I am creating `a library` and I wanted to use `Date` instead of `String dateOfBirth`. I know that the Date is quite old now and it is not used so what would you advise me to do? Shall I use Callendar instead?

What I am looking for is basically setting the `date of birth for users` of the library as well as assigning `release date for books`.

Thank you

Comment: Use classes from `java.time`, for a date of birth a `LocalDate` seems suitable.

Comment: Not Calendar.  That's just as old.  I suggest you read this:  https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html

Comment: Date and Calendar are both legacy. Use the classes in the `java.time` package instead, so for example `LocalDate` for a birthday.

Comment: Use LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now(); as much possible as you can.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for this task:

```
import java.time.LocalDate; 

public class Person {
    //Local variable for dateOfBirth
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;    

    public Person(int year, int month, int day) {
        //See API also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-
        dateOfBirth = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    }

    //Getter
    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

And for test purposes:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creating new Person-object with birthday on March 30th, 2000
        Person p = new Person(2000, 3, 30);
        System.out.println(p.getDateOfBirth());
    }
}
```